# using conditions to print values in ireport

Tags: jasper-reports, conditional-statements

I am trying to use conditions to print value in table

I have three columns A B C

```
A is string
B is integer
C is integer
```

my condition is If column A == "user"
then print value in column B or make it null

```
($F{A}.equals("USER")?null:$F{B})
```

this gives type casting error

```
<jr:column width="15" uuid="733459e9-1ed8-4ce2-a74d-87dc078b1382">
                                <jr:tableFooter height="29" rowSpan="1"/>
                                <jr:columnFooter style="table 8_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                                <jr:detailCell style="table 8_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="bd3860a4-999a-4121-a701-3481a4fdf98e"/>
                                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="8"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOP}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:detailCell>
                            </jr:column>
                            <jr:column width="15" uuid="2e7fa82c-7f28-4af6-a63d-ae468afeea32">
                                <jr:tableFooter height="29" rowSpan="1"/>
                                <jr:columnFooter style="table 8_CH" height="30" rowSpan="1"/>
                                <jr:detailCell style="table 8_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                                    <textField isBlankWhenNull="true">
                                        <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="15" height="20" uuid="33707346-9121-4010-8c12-981eb9f4de77">
                                            <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{TOP}.endsWith("NN")?null:$F{COP}]]></printWhenExpression>
                                        </reportElement>
                                        <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                            <font size="8"/>
                                        </textElement>
                                        <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{COP}]]></textFieldExpression>
                                    </textField>
                                </jr:detailCell>
                            </jr:column>
```

Comment: What version of *iReport* are you using? You should post the *jrxml* file

Comment: can you help me in query the code is three page long

Comment: Especially show the lines around your `($F{A}.equals("USER")?null:$F{B})`.

Comment: i have added some part of my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$F{TOP}.endsWith("NN")?null:$F{COP}` this should not be in the "Print When Expression" field, for this is a boolean expression field: like print when expression if this = that. Like for instance if I never want to see that field I would put `0==1` in the print when expression field. So remove that line from the print when expression field.

You want to put the line in the field itself. So right-click the field `TOP` (I am assuming this is the field you want to change if it ends with NN) and select Edit Expression and put this line in replacement of `$F{TOP}`

Comment: Error filling print... java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean 
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Boolean
This the error i get